# Are json files added to WebApplicationBuilder checked for values in LIFO order?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

When trying to build a .Net Core app, I built appsettings.json files for Development, Staging, and Production. I was under the impression that the app would then automatically check the files for the matching environment (i.e. appsettings.ENVNAME.json).  However, my experience led me to believe:

1. These files are not automatically loaded and must be added (e.g.

```
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").AddJsonFile("appsettings.Development.json").AddJsonFile("appsettings.Staging.json").AddJsonFile("appsettings.Production.json")
```

2. The files are then checked for values in LIFO order, i.e. if the files are added as above, the Production file will be checked first, regardless of what environment the app is running in

As such, I built my app with

```
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{builder.Environment.EnvironmentName}.json")
```

which seems to be working.

Am I correct on this functionality? And is there any way to implement an automatic check based on environment without making it this explicit, similar to how the transforms are automatically performed in web.configs in Framework?

Answer (score 0):

appsettings.json will be loaded automaticlly by default default JsonConfigurationProvider in your project,youc could check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#appsettingsjson),and if you add the customer json file contains the same key ,it would override the former value,It has been explained in the same document

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't see the applicability of ASP.NET Core Blazor CSS isolation
 to my question.

Comment: Sorry,I copied the wrong link,it has been fixed now